# Overriding values in sub-subchart with global values

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

i have a subchart named sub-chart and inside of that there's another subchart called sub-subchart. i need to override values of the sub-subchart. how can i do it? and why use camelcase the name of the sub-subchart (subSubchart instead of sub-subchart)?

i have tried writing the global values file like this:

```yaml
subchart:
  sub-subchart:
    enabled: true
    rbac: 
      enabled: false
```

and it didn't work at all

tried this way:

```yaml
subchart:
  subSubchart:
    enabled: true
    rbac: 
      enabled: false
```

subSubchart is enabled but rbac still is created